# Search Engine Robots Section Can't Be Changed (Grayed Out)

Tags: magento2.2

I have a fresh install of Magento 2.2. This is a test site, so we need to hide it from search engines.

I found the Search Engine Robots section under - Content - Design - Configuration - Our theme, but the options are grayed out and cannot be changed.

Is it possible that there is a setting we are missing to unlock this section? We tested 1.9 and did not have this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just faced the same issue. I was able to edit that by either editing Global or Website configuration but not from Store View.

```
Content > Design > Configuration > {Select Website}
```

Store View has always been grayed out for me. However, when I change Search Engine Robots from Website, the change gets carried to Store View.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Search Engine Robots has a Website scope. Change the robots on the website and then on the store view click on the "Use Default Value". Then the changes will be applied to the Store View.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to `Content > Design > Configuration` select your current theme from the grid and click on the `Edit` link from the Action column.

You can see the setting for `Search Engine Robots`.

I don't think so it is editable in Magento 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Wow there are some complicated answers here....

When you select the theme from 'design and configuration' often the value is inherited from the master template so make sure your Scope is Main Website. Then you can edit it just fine, nice hack though :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a workaround that how can one edit/add/update the **robots.txt** portion.[image]